# Fast conversion of single dimension array to two dimensional 'column' array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, initialization

Are there any built-in functions (or fast implementations) in Java to convert a single-dimension array of size `[n]` to a two-dimensional array of size `[n][1]`?

For example:

```
double[] x = new double[]{1, 2, 3};
double[][] x2D = new double[][]{{1}, {2}, {3}};
```

Comment: A loop isn't enough ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such built-in *function* - but can be done using `Stream` or a simple loop as already suggested above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a built-in function to convert a single dimension array to a two-dimensional one, sadly there isn't one.

However, as it has been pointed out in the comments, you could use **streams to reach a fair compact way to initialize your two-dimensional array** from a single-dimension one. Basically, you could define your matrix's dimension from the array's length and then rely on a stream to copy the array's elements within the two-dimensional array.

```
double[] x = new double[]{1, 2, 3};
double[][] x2D = new double[x.length][1];
IntStream.range(0, x.length).forEach(i -> x2D[i][0] = x[i]);
```

Or in a more concise writing, you could immediately initialize your two-dimensional array with a stream where each element is mapped to a `double[]` and then collect each one of them into a further array.

```
double[] x = new double[]{1, 2, 3};
double[][] mat = Arrays.stream(x).mapToObj(i -> new double[]{i}).toArray(double[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.setAll` method can be used:

```
double[] x     = {1, 2, 3};
double[][] x2D = new double[x.length][];

Arrays.setAll(x2D, i -> new double[]{x[i]});
```